# Google Conversion Tracking without using JavaScript - Image Pixels Will Work Though

Tags: google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

A system I need to install conversion tracking in does not allow for JavaScript but does allow for image pixels.

Do you know if this following script will be sufficient?  I would replace the ID & Label placeholders with the actual references form the Ad Account

```
<img height="1" width="1" style="border-style:none;" alt="" src="//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/1111111111/?label=2222222222&amp;guid=ON&amp;script=0"/>
```

Regular HTMP Pixel

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Ads: 11111111111 -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=AW-898705991"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'AW-11111111111 ');
</script>

<!-- Event snippet conversion page -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {'send_to': 'AW-111111111/2222222222'});
</script>
```